# How can I add a second layer to a video?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, video-sequence-editor

I want to add an object to a video. I tried to set transparent background, but it doesn't work. In VSE preview is want I want, and render result is what I get.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used cycles for rendering and I've simply forgot to enable **Transparent** option. Go to **Render Panel > Film** and make sure the checkbox is enabled.

[image].

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the sequencer enabled in the Post Processing section of your scene.

[image]

Comment: Sequencer is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

**settings for cycles**

1. > **Render** panel > **Film** > Tick **Transperant**
2. Select the scene strip you added and on right-hand side you will find a panel (if hidden "toggle n")

   > go to **blend** which by default is "Cross" make it "Alpha over"
3. Render

[image: Rendering using cycles]

**settings for Blender render engine Simple**

[image: Blender render setting]